# Covariant derivative notation

Tags: tensors

I saw the following notation in a paper: $T_{ab;cd}$. Does this mean $\nabla_c\nabla_d T_{ab}$, or $\nabla_d\nabla_c T_{ab}$? I couldn't find a reference on a quick internet search.

Comment: When I use similar notation, I always intend the latter expression.  However, it’s difficult to answer your question precisely without knowing the conventions of the authors.

Comment: I believe the latter is more common, but you can’t count on it. Whenever you read anything in differential geometry, you have to figure what notation conventions the author is using. I usually rewrite all the formulas using my own conventions. This implies you have to adopt your own set of conventions.